# Mean Value Theorem and Lower Bound

Tags: calculus

**PROBLEM**: I wonder why my answer is wrong.

**QUESTION**: Suppose $x(t)$ satisfies the hypothesis of the Mean value Theorem (MVT), that is, $x(t)$ is continuous on $A \le t \le B$ and differentiable on $A \lt t \lt B$ and $m$ is the lower bound, then: $$m \le x'(t)$$ for all $t$ such that $$A \lt t \lt B$$

Let us consider the MVT on shorter intervals. The strongest conclusion we can draw is:

[image]

MVT says it is differentiable over the interval $A \lt t \lt B$ and since differential is $$\frac{x(b)-x(a)}{b-a}$$ therefore $$ m \le \frac{x(b)-x(a)}{b-a}$$ for all $a,b$ over the same interval. Why my answer is wrong ? Why the interval changed to $A \le t \le B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that there is a $t\in(a,b)$ (open interval) such that 
$$x'(t)=\frac{x(b)-x(a)}{b-a}.$$
Hence if $A\leq a<b\leq B$ then $t\in(a,b)\subseteq (A,B)$, and
$$m\leq x'(t)=\frac{x(b)-x(a)}{b-a}.$$
So the strongest conclusion is just the last one!

Comment: I guess MIT course on [edX](https://www.edx.org/course/calculus-1b-integration)  just over-complicates things. Like you, they could have simply mentioned (a,b) is an interval inside (A,B) and a,b are two distinct points. Thanks